# Ripping DVDs conserving languages and subtitles

Tags: dvd, ripping, subtitles

I have a collection of DVDs which occupy a lot of space and keep getting scratched by misbehaving children.
While I'm working on educating my kids, I'm actually looking for a technical solution to my problem :)
I would like to rip all these DVDs while satisfying the following requirements:
* Keep original image quality (or close)
* Keep original soundtracks in several languages
* Keep subtitles of various languages

I used HandBrake to rip DVDs which worked pretty well for image and audio, but I can't keep all the subtitles. I was only able to keep one set of subtitles as "burned in"

Any advice?

P.S. I'm a Linux user, so windows/osx only software is not an option
P.P.S I'm aware of the fact that I can make an ISO, and if there's no other option, I will. However, I prefer to use modern encodings (H.264/VP8) and enjoy ~x4 smaller files

Comment: Is making an ISO image an option for you? You could mount the image anytime (e.g. using [DaemonTools](http://www.filehippo.com/download_daemon_tools/) and have the "original" DVD at hand.

Comment: It is currently my fallback option, but it is ~x4 bigger then an equivalent H.264 video, and less practical (only double-click playback that worked is using VLC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/) (Linux version available in forum) to rip the entire DVD to an MKV file, then use some utility or another to transcode the video tracks to h.264 (and audio to aac, if you wanted).  You could even use Handbrake to handle the transcoding, then a bit of mkvextract/mkvmerge wizardry to pull the subtitles out of the original MKV and mux them into the smaller MKV.  Then you could delete the large MKV.

Answer (score 0):

You can rip them to .iso (image) format, which takes a lot of space (roughly 7GB per DVD) but preserves the disc 1-to-1.

Comment: Thanks, this is my fallback option, but I prefer H.264 and smaller files